# First try at HTTPClient in Xamarin.Forms not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, httpclient

I know this should be simple, so I am obviously missing something.

I am writing a very simple Xamarin.Forms application with this as the `MainPage.xaml.cs` of the Shared project.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyClass myClassInstance { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DownloadDataAsync();            
    }

    private async void DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        string page = @"http://www.blaw.com:80/foo/bar"; 

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(page, string.Empty));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);  <---  BONK!
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
                using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(responseString))
                {
                    myClassInstance = (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(tr);
                }
            }
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this on my Android device, it never gets past the GetAsync line (marked with <-- BONK!). It doesn't throw an exception, and in never makes it to the `if` statement, it just returns from the method without doing anything at all.

I have enabled the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and INTERNET permissions in the Android Manifest.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you write "uri" to the console to verify that it is the correct URL you are expecting?

Comment: Also, does this work on an iOS device or are you getting the same issue?

Comment: I used a breakpoint to verify that the uri is correct.  Also, if I use this exact code in a windows console app, it works fine.   I haven't tried compiling for iOS yet... the iPhone I am to test with is not here yet.

Comment: What about in an iOS Simulator?

Comment: Everything looks fine. I would suggest trying to hit the endpoint with Postman and verify that you can read data from it. Then I would check if I am sending the correct headers on the client configuration.

Comment: Also you should [Avoid async void](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Comment: I tried the URL(http://www.blaw.com:80/foo/bar) in the browser, he needs to log in, can you provide API documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling asynchronous method from constructor is not a good idea. This will work in console applications but not on UI applications. Because this will block the UI thread, and control never returns to the code due to deadlock.

If you can call your async method in OnAppearing, it should work fine.

Comment: Even though the call comes after the InitializeComponent() call?